# Manage functions and function bodies updates

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql has some insane features which I would like to use.
Functions and Triggers are the first things popping in my mind, but there are a lot more that can be helpful.

My biggest concern is that I have to store a function or a trigger in the database with create/destroy/update.

When I write code, I'll usually update a file, deploy and my project gets auto updated, but with Postgresql I would need a kind of framework that possibly searches for functions that have been updated in my files and update those functions in the database.

Is there any such framework or are there any alternatives to store/update functions in postgresql? Same for triggers.

Comment: Liquibase can help you with that. Also if you write the functions as `create or replace` in most of the cases a `drop function` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. Will it have consequences if I perform the create or replace on a in-use database which could be using that function? And also, it will still require me to run manually CREATE OR REPLACE for each function I update, while I expect this to happen automatically either when I save file or with some kind of `git push`. Although looks like Liquidbase might fit, I'm reading.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I read about Liquidbase, but it still feels like I have to manage the changes to the functions while `git` should do that for me like in any other programming language (it's fine for table changes, not for functions)

Comment: Of course you need to store the Liquibase changelog and the related SQL scripts in a version control system like git. Git itself does "do" anything with those files, it merely stores versions. Liquibase offers an execution environment to run those scripts

Comment: Yes I know this... Damn it's really hard to explain what I mean, sorry. It was an analogy mostly: I want to be able to change the function body in a file, save in my text editor and the database should start using the new function body, without me needing to type any kind of "create function" anywhere

Comment: This is not how a database works. The only way you can change something in the database is to run a DDL or DML statement. You need _some_ tool that runs this for you. Why don't you just load the SQL script in your SQL tool to edit run it from there?

Comment: Because while for data is reasonable, functions are not data, they are just piece of my software logic, tracking back what I changed and running create function on every new/modified function file every time is something I really don't like, tools should be doing that for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep research, I couldn't find any proper tool to do what I wanted. Unless something is developed in the future, nothing is available for this kind of workflow currently.